# how to add time interval code to the SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ( (SELECT 'used' FROM b_names_1) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'used' FROM b_names_2)) AS t
WHERE 'used' = 1`

This code words very well..

But I want to sort the results with time intervals, so when I tried just to add this lines at the bottom, it doesnt work:

```
AND registration_date_time >= STR_TO_DATE( '2013-01-28 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AND registration_date_time < STR_TO_DATE( '2013-02-02 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )
```

The piece of code looked like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ( (SELECT 'used' FROM b_names_1) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'used' FROM b_names_2)) AS t
WHERE 'used' = 1 AND registration_date_time >= STR_TO_DATE( '2013-01-28 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AND registration_date_time < STR_TO_DATE( '2013-02-02 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )
```

it gives me the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'registration_date_time' in 'where clause'

any idea how to correctly implement that date code to the SQL?

Comment: You need to prefix the column with table name I believe

Comment: Does this return anything? WHERE 'used' = 1 -- did you mean to use ticks instead of apostrophes: WHERE `USED` = 1?

Answer (score 1):

Those columns have to come **FROM** somewhere, add them to the inner queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM ( 
    (SELECT 'used', registration_date_time FROM b_names_1) 
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'used', registration_date_time FROM b_names_2)
) AS t
WHERE 'used' = 1 
AND registration_date_time >= STR_TO_DATE( '2013-01-28 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) 
AND registration_date_time < STR_TO_DATE( '2013-02-02 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )
```